Problem enabling perl module stream AlmaLinux 8.10
I have an issue with our AlmaLinux 8.10 systems that they suddenly have issues with perl dependancies. It tuns out that the current active perl stream is 5.26 (dnf module list perl*) but some packages want to install the versions that are only available for 5.32 (local own repo). The packages are available for 5.32, but it complains it cannot install both of them.
cannot install both perl-libs-4:5.32.1-473.module_el8.10.0+3779+d5938d28.x86_64 from almalinux8x-repo and perl-libs-4:5.26.3-422.el8.0.1.x86_64 from @System

This on several packages. We use own own local repo as the machines cannot access the internet. Thus the only package available is the 'latest 5:32' versions.
when I try to enable module perl:5.32 it an error:
[bogusadmin@bogusserver1 ~]$ sudo dnf module enable perl:5.32
Last metadata expiration check: 0:04:35 ago on Tue 16 Jul 2024 02:23:47 PM CEST.
Error: Problems in request:
Modular dependency problems:

 Problem 1: module perl:5.26:8020020201210074505:9edba152.x86_64 from almalinux8x-repo conflicts with module(perl:5.32) provided by perl:5.32:8060020220420215943:103a1005.x86_64 from almalinux8x-repo
  - module perl:5.32:8060020220420215943:103a1005.x86_64 from almalinux8x-repo conflicts with module(perl:5.26) provided by perl:5.26:8020020201210074505:9edba152.x86_64 from almalinux8x-repo
  - module freeradius:3.0:8050020211012203145:ab0f257b.x86_64 from almalinux8x-repo requires module(perl:5.26), but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
 Problem 2: module perl:5.26:8020020201210074505:9edba152.x86_64 from almalinux8x-repo conflicts with module(perl:5.32) provided by perl:5.32:8080020230404080540:9edba152.x86_64 from almalinux8x-repo
  - module perl:5.32:8080020230404080540:9edba152.x86_64 from almalinux8x-repo conflicts with module(perl:5.26) provided by perl:5.26:8020020201210074505:9edba152.x86_64 from almalinux8x-repo
  - module freeradius:3.0:8050020220203082853:aa8850cc.x86_64 from almalinux8x-repo requires module(perl:5.26), but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
 Problem 3: module perl:5.26:8020020201210074505:9edba152.x86_64 from almalinux8x-repo conflicts with module(perl:5.32) provided by perl:5.32:8100020240409203632:9edba152.x86_64 from almalinux8x-repo
  - module perl:5.32:8100020240409203632:9edba152.x86_64 from almalinux8x-repo conflicts with module(perl:5.26) provided by perl:5.26:8020020201210074505:9edba152.x86_64 from almalinux8x-repo
  - module freeradius:3.0:8060020220503123814:fbe42456.x86_64 from almalinux8x-repo requires module(perl:5.26), but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests

I also cannot disable the old 5.26 first and then enable 5.32, it refuses. It just drops me back to the prompt. already tried deleting ALL perl packages and switch then, but still a no go.
As these machines have no connectivity to the internet I have to install packages through our repo server which is a current full mirror of the AlmaLinux 8 repo + EPEL8 but I have some options to add rpm packages ourselfs as I also have a repo called middleware with our own application packages.
Does anyone have an idea to switch to the new 5.32 module stream for perl???
P.S. Also a fresh install from the minimal ISO, en then updating the OS with our own repo it get the same result.

5.32 modules are not compatible with Perl 5.26. You can try installing the modules from CPAN (i.e., on a machine with internet access, download the .tar.gz and install it using the cpan client).

Sounds like the solution is to install a perl 5.32 with perlbrew and re-install the needed system modules in the perlbrew with cpanm after reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733482/how-do-i-install-cpan-modules-while-using-perlbrew

I will try this asap.
